# How to connect to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

How do i write the connection string to connect to mysql database with this info:
Using php connection string

1. Database Details:

   - phpmyadmin url: https://medicalng.com/phpmyadmin
   - host: localhost
   - database: wlfmedic_ptest1
   - username: wlfmedic_ptest1
   - password: Prog@te$t104

Comment: [a look at the manual would help](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php) (linked PDO, you could also choose `mysqli`, _don't_ choose the deprecated `mysql` extension.

Comment: [Read the php documentation](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysqli-connect.php). And don't provide credentials, even for testing purposes.

Comment: Remove the password from your question!

Comment: Please look on [mysqli connection](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php). plz share the code what you have tried. Dont share secure credentials details.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the very basics of using MySQL and PHP, which would be covered in any tutorial or book.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?PHP

$user_name = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "addressbook";
$server = "127.0.0.1";

$db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);

$db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);

if ($db_found) {

print "Database Found ";
mysql_close($db_handle);

}
else {

print "Database NOT Found ";

}

?>
```

> [also you can refer this link](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php13p1.html)

Comment: As I've commented elsewhere, the mysql_* functions are deprecated.

Comment: @stwalkerster is right. Reference link also refer to mysql_* functions. In future mysql_* function will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Something basic, not secure tho.

```
<?php
mysql_connect(localhost, ##YOUR USERNAME##, ##YOUR PASSWORD##);
mysql_select_db('##YOUR DATABASE NAME##');


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM emails");
?>
```

and updated mysqli http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/basic-php-mysqli-usage

Comment: The mysql_* functions are deprecated in PHP. It's strongly recommended to use either mysqli_* or PDO.

Comment: @stwalkerster Very true, I have updated my post with a link.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysqli`. `mysqli` [connection](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) is like this:

```
$host = "localhost";
$database = "wlfmedic_ptest1";
$username = "wlfmedic_ptest1";
$password = 'Prog@te$t104';

$connection = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database);
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){ //To show error if fails to connect
    die(mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

Comment: please use `xxxx` for password. Password should be removed from question too.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

  $db_hostName="localhost";

  $databaseName= "wlfmedic_ptest1";

  $db_userName= "wlfmedic_ptest1";

  $db_password= "Prog@te$t104";

  $con=mysql_connect($db_hostName,$db_userName,$db_password);
    if(!$con){
      die ("Could Not successfully with DataBase".mysql_error());
    }else{
      echo "Connect connect with succssfully .";
    }

    $db=mysql_select_db($db_databaseName,$con);
    if(!$db)
    {
      echo "Can notConnect with Bd Social";
    }
    else
    {
      echo "Conncet With Bd Social";
    }

?>

try this ..
```